# Color not appearing on LaTeX (TeXpad)

Tags: fonts, macros, graphics, equations, color

I am trying to color code parts of the equation on TeXpad (a LaTeX app on the iPad), but for some reason, the colors are not appearing on the desired parts of the equation. Here’s the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts, bm}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\DeclareUSUnit\DeclareSIUnit
\let\US\SI
\DeclareUSUnit\mile{mi}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\noindent
PM: $J = \phi\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right),t_f\right) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)dt$ \newline
General problem: $\min J = \textcolor{red}{\phi\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right)\right)} + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)dt $
    \begin{mini*}|s|
            {\substack{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u}}}{J = \phi\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right),t_f\right) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\mathcal{L}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)dt}{}{}
            \addConstraint{\dot{\mathbf{x}} =}{\mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{u},t\right)}
            \addConstraint{\mathbf{x}\left(0\right)}{= \mathbf{x}_0,}{\quad\text{(Initial condition)}}
            \addConstraint{\Psi\left(\mathbf{x}_f,t_f\right) }{= 0,} {\quad\text{(Terminal constraints)}}
    \end{mini*}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document} `
```

Here’s what I am getting:

[image]

Can anyone explain what’s going on with TeXpad or the code itself?

Comment: provide the editable MWE, so that anyone can check the give the solution.

Comment: Hello, just edited it

Comment: Don't show only a snippet,  show a complete example that can be compiled starting with \documentclass.

Comment: The code is not the problem, it shows the color correctly on my system. Can you use color in other places, in normal text, or using the `\color` command instead of `\textcolor`? Do you get any errors from Texpad somewhere about missing packages, undefined color names, etc? By the way, I have edited the question to show the correct code formatting, for a multi-line code block you use three backticks instead of one (which also adds syntax highlighting).

Comment: I don’t get any errors notifications regarding the colors at all in Texpad.

Comment: @Marijn Which system did you use?

Comment: I used TeX Live on Ubuntu. Maybe it is a bug in the previewer? When you make a pdf in Texpad and open that pdf in another pdf viewer, do you still not see the colors?

Comment: @Marijn I tried that for another file that had color issues, the pdf in another viewer was still black and white

Comment: Does the issue appear both with local typesetting and with cloud typesetting?

Comment: @Marijn just tried out cloud typesetting, and it worked because it used pdflatex; on the other hand, local typesetting uses texpadtex

Comment: In that case you could try to file a bug report with Texpad, they should fix this :)

Comment: @Marijn Will do.